# Python: Add Processing Time to Output CSV File

Tags: python, csv, time

The code below creates a pandas dataframe and outputs it into a csv file. It also clocks the processing time. How would I add the processing time to the csv file?

Thank you for your time.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
def procedure():
    time.sleep(0)
t0 = time.clock()
y=pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4],'two':[3,5,7,5],'three':[2,3,4,9],'four':[4,3,1,0],})
y.to_csv('temp1.csv')
procedure()
print (time.clock()-t0)
```

Comment: are you on windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
finish_time = time.time() - start_time
```

To get the processing time you can use your code like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
def procedure():
    time.sleep(0)
start_time = time.time()
y=pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4],'two':[3,5,7,5],'three':[2,3,4,9],'four':[4,3,1,0],})
y.to_csv('temp1.csv')
procedure()
finish_time = time.time() - start_time
print (finish_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in append mode to add the time to the end:

```
...
procedure()
elapsed = time.clock()-t0
with open('temp1.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(elapsed))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indents are off:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

def procedure():
    time.sleep(0)
    y=pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4],'two':[3,5,7,5],'three':[2,3,4,9],'four':[4,3,1,0],})
    y.to_csv('temp1.csv')

start_time = time.time()    
procedure()
finish_time = time.time() - start_time
print (finish_time)
```